# How to activate COLOR PRINT from Mac?

Tags: mac, printing, printer, colors, macos-catalina

I have macOS Catalina version 10.15.6 (19G73). My printer is HP Color LaserJet MFP M477fdn. When I show a picture file from the Finder in the Mac Preview then it is shown in color. When I press Cmd+P to show the Print Preview, the print preview is shown only in GRAYSCALE, and when I print it, it is always printed in Grayscale. (But I can print in Color on this printer from a Windows computer).

So how can I activate the COLOR PRINT from the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I've an almost identical printer (MFP M477fdw).
The only potential control I can see is deep inside the print prefs… Printer Features > JCL which has an option to print colour as grey. (I've no idea how anyone would find that by accident… I thought I'd been through every option;)

[image]

Comment: I don't have the "Printer Features" option. However, I solved the problem by adding another printer driver version in System Settings -> Printers and Scanners, clicked the + button. Then, instead of the preselected "AirPrint" I selected "Postscript". Now the printing in color works!

Comment: OK, never used airprint. Mine is on the wired ethernet & accessed from desktop Macs.

Comment: I also don't use Airprint but a wired connection. I don't know why AirPrint has been a default setting. I also don't know how to change air print to Postscript in an existing printer configuration.

Comment: I don't see anything like that in my Printer/Scanner prefs - https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9hTE.png

Comment: Here you can see the + button: https://i.imgur.com/g6fOUt8.jpg

Comment: Kind/Art should be 'HP Colour  Laser jet…'. You also seem to have the printer shared, which it shouldn't be if it's directly on the network. If you didn't start the initial setup with HP's "Easy Start" then it might not have installed the correct support.

Comment: 1. I don't know what you mean by "Kind/Art". 2. I have the printer shared because I need the printer also in a Parallels virtual machine. (If I don't share the printer then it is not available in the VM). 3. I don't remember how the initial printer setup was started - I assume it was automatic.

Comment: 1. English 'kind' HP LaserJet… or your german 'Art; Allegemeiner PS Drücker <-this is wrong. 2. That makes no difference, a VM should still be able to find it on the network [if you have default shared settings or at least have the VM on the same subnet]. You don't 'share' a network printer, it's not "yours" to share, it's on the network. 3. If you don't use the HP setup, you don't get the full set of services, including Easy Scan etc, & by the look of it, the correct model profiles for 'kind' or 'art'.

Comment: The kind name "Allgemeiner PostScript-Drucker" is derived from the fact that when adding it I changed it from AirPrint to PostScript. The other two printer configurations (the ones that print only GrayScale) have the kind name "Unknown-AirPrint". So the kind "PostScript" is not wrong.

Comment: By comparing your screenshot with mine, I have also noted that the German translation is misleading: The English word "Idle" is translated to "Inaktiv" which could lead to misunderstandings. A better translation IMO would be "Untätig". But there is no real optimal translation of the word "Idle" in this context.

Comment: Postscript is wrong because it *should* know exactly what the printer is. That it doesn't, means you're missing something in the setup that would have been added by Easy Start.